# Jquery toggleClass runs multiple times instead of once for this dom element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an mvc view that outputs a bunch of divs. All have a class of userproject. That is the only class on the divs. However when I call toggleClass which is supposed to animate the div from a small div to a big div in order to see all the text. The animation runs once for each div on the page on the same div.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".userproject").click(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("userprojectclicked", "slow");
    });

});
```

css

```
.userproject
{
    float: left;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.userprojectclicked
{
    width: 900px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: green;
}
```

view with the below div output in a loop.

```
<div class="userproject">

<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => @Model.Name) : @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Name)</p>
<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => @Model.Description) : @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Description)</p>
<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => @Model.UserId) : @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.UserId)</p>
<p>@Html.LabelFor(m => @Model.CategoryId) : @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.CategoryId)</p>

</div>
```

The problem is that the animation occurs once for every div on the page ... but it happens to the same div so it grows big and then small ... big and then small ... etc. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Nopes man - works like a rocket: (see here) http://jsfiddle.net/w5nz6/ :) let me know if this helped,

Comment: That seems kind of bizarre. Could you create a demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: wow jsfiddle is an awesome website. It does definitely work on jsfiddle as you pointed out tats ... however its still not working in my project. I was also able to create a test project and it worked in that project. However even with the exact same code it still freaks out in my original project ... I have no idea why ...

Comment: Sometmes, weird behavior like this is caused by an unclosed div or a missing end quote mark which inadvertently causes some HTML weirdness.  I'd suggest either checking your HTML manually or running it through a validation check and see if there are any HTML goofs.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I will check that out tonight. It's quite possible because I've got partials in there and I might have a duplicate div or as you say an unclosed one or something. Hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery was in a partial view that was rendered in a regular view inside a loop. This meant that there was many copies of the jquery code placed in the original view. So each copy of the jquery was only running once but I had many functions rendered because of how the page was structured. In the future I will likely not be including jquery / javascript in my partial views.